# How to set jQuery ID for bunch of php generated DIVs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using a Lightbox gallery for my website, the jQuery code is

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {    
    $('.tosrus a').tosrus({
        pagination : {
            add : true,
            type : "thumbnails"
        },
        buttons : true
    });
});
```

My galleries will be generated via PHP, and each gallery will have different images, if I use class to detect the gallery it will show all the images in the page.
So I should use ID to detect each gallery but the thing is I'm not very familiar with jQuery at all.

My PHP code is

```
$j = 0;
<div id="tosrus-<?= $j++ ?>" class="tosrus thumbs">  
<a href="<? the_sub_field('images-list'); ?>">
                            <img src="<? the_sub_field('images-list'); ?>"></a>
</div>
```

So the result will be like `tosrus-1,` `tosrus-2` for each div.

Anybody have any idea how can i get this work?

Comment: `$('div[id^="tosrus"] a')` will select all elements with an id starting with `tosrus` and then the `a` within. is that what you want?

Comment: what do you want to do with the images/galeries once they all have an ID?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this question is confusing, because if your solutions works, why can't he just uses classes?

Comment: @RST I mentioned that each DIV will have different images, so i should set different jQuery for each DIV, like '$('#tosrus-0 a').tosrus' '$('#tosrus-1 a').tosrus' does it makes sense?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It is like to target a class.

Comment: not to me, but I am sure someone else will understand.

Comment: Why dont you just loop? `$('.tosrus').each(function(){$(this).find('a').tosrus(...);})`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specifically assign an indexed id to interact with items at a specific index--you can use the [:nth-of-type selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) for this instead.

For example:

```
$("div:nth-of-type(1)").hide();
```

Live example here: http://jsbin.com/ciraruhuhimi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

From the Jquery selector [attribute contains prefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) you can get the div element

```
$( "div[id|='tosrus']" )
```

This selector is used to get the elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).